# Get DropDownList item, make database query and send the results to another webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have controller that get list of objects from my database and return this list:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var list = db.MyObjects.Where(x => x.family == "Web").ToArray();
    list = list.Distinct(new MyObjectByProtocolComparer())
               .OrderBy(x => x.fileName)
               .ToArray();
    ViewBag.Files = list;
    return View();
}
```

Index.cshtml:

This return list is inserted into `DropDownList`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownList(
           "File", new SelectList(ViewBag.Files,
           "protocol_site", "protocol_site"),
           "Select webmail site",
           new { style = "vertical-align:middle;" }
           )
        <button type="submit">Select</button>
    </div>
}
```

After choose one item from and hit the button my other controller method is get the `DropDownList` item name and make new database query:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string File)
{
    var list = db.MyObjects.Where(x => x.protocol == File).ToArray();
    ViewBag.Files = list;
    return View();
}
```

What happen now is that the new query is inserted again into my `DropDownList` but i want this list to send to another page and from this page i wand to show this over `ListView`.
how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send it to another view, you'd better redirect to a new action instead of displaying your form again !

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string File)
{
    // Some validation logic
    return RedirectToAction("ShowList", new { protocol = File });
}

public ActionResult ShowList(string protocol)
{
    var list = db.MyObjects.Where(x => x.protocol == protocol).ToArray();
    ViewBag.Files = list;
    return View();
}
```

The view called `ShowList` will display your items as a listView if it is what you defined.

EDIT :

As you want to display your list in the same view, you have to give a different name to your list, because `ViewBag.Files` is already used by your drop down list.

Also, as you want to update your list based on your current selection in the drop down list, i suggest you to use `Ajax helpers`. Here's a good link about this : http://geekswithblogs.net/blachniet/archive/2011/08/03/updating-partial-views-with-unobtrusive-ajax-in-mvc-3.aspx

Basically, your view (index.cshtml) should use an Ajax form, and prepare a empty `div` containing your list. The action called by your form would return a partial view, inserted in that div, without refreshing the whole view.

Comment: and what about my view (Index.cshtml) ? what i need to change ?

Comment: Index.cshtml is what you use to display your form and your dropdownlist. Do you need to display them anyway, and to add a listview in it, or do you want the listview in a separate view ?

Comment: I prefer after choose my item and hit button to display listview on the same form so after choose another item this listview will update

Comment: Can i have an code example (i am an new developer and its looks very complicate) ?